# What's the difference between 特色 and 特点?

Tags: difference, vocabulary

What's the difference between 特色 and 特点? When should I use 特色 and when 特点? Please give me some examples. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

特色 **distinguishing** feature; quality; characteristic

特点 **unique/ special** feature; quality; characteristic

> 特色 is the distinguishing characteristics of something

Example: 鋪榻榻米是和室的特色 -  using tatami mats is a distinguishing characteristic of Japanese style rooms

*the use of tatami mats indicate it is Japanese style*

> 特点 is the special features of something

Example: 鋪榻榻米是和室的特点 - using tatami mats is a special characteristic of Japanese style rooms

*tatami mats is a unique feature of Japanese style rooms*